# SQL Server SELECT where any column contains 'x'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

Using SQL Server 2008, say I have a table called `testing` with 80 columns and I want to find a value called `foo`.

I can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM testing 
WHERE COLNAME = 'foo'
```

Is it possible I can query all 80 columns and return all the results where `foo` is contained in any of the 80 columns?

Comment: Yes you can. You can add allo columns with `or` in your where statement. `SELECT * FROM testing where COLNAME = 'foo' or COLNAME2 = 'foo' or ....`

Comment: it can be helpful http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm

Comment: @Jens What a pain. Especially if you have thousands of tables, each with hundreds of fields, and you're not familiar with many of them.

Comment: @Michael maybe. But if you have tables with hundreds of fields, sounds like bad db design

Comment: Duplicate of: [How can I search all columns in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922744/how-can-i-search-all-columns-in-a-table)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM testing 
WHERE 'foo' in (col1, col2, col3, . . . );
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible without defining every column name? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @nsilva . . . Yes, but you wouldn't want to do that.  One method I can think of would involve a rather complicated XML trick.  You can get the list of columns from `information_schema.columns` if you are averse to typing them.

Comment: Yes @Gordon!
 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'testing';' -will give you all table values together.

Comment: @eMi . . . That is a rather generic statement to make about working code.  You could just try it out.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it works if you search for the exact word "foo" but it doesn't work in a way with LIKE "%foo%". You should add that variant too. It is different and not possible with the IN.

Comment: SELECT * FROM testing WHERE col1 LIKE '%foo%' OR col2 LIKE '%foo%' ...

Comment: Oh. My. Goodness.  I have been using MySQL for something like 20 years and had never realised that IN() can be used this way around.  I feel silly.  This has really simplified a query I just had to make.  Thank you!!!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it's by far the simplest way of doing this.

Answer (score 10):

**First Method(Tested)**
First get list of columns in string variable separated by commas and then you can search 'foo' using that variable by use of `IN`

Check stored procedure below which first gets columns and then searches for string:

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(128)

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Set up the name of the table here :
SET @TABLE_NAME = 'testing'
-- Set up the name of the schema here, or just leave set to 'dbo' :
SET @SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbo'

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @vvc_ColumnName VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @vvc_ColumnList VARCHAR(MAX)

IF @SCHEMA_NAME =''
  BEGIN
  PRINT 'Error : No schema defined!'
  RETURN
  END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables T JOIN sys.schemas S
      ON T.schema_id=S.schema_id
      WHERE T.Name=@TABLE_NAME AND S.name=@SCHEMA_NAME)
  BEGIN
  PRINT 'Error : The table '''+@TABLE_NAME+''' in schema '''+
      @SCHEMA_NAME+''' does not exist in this database!' 
  RETURN
 END

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT   CASE WHEN PATINDEX('% %',C.name) > 0 
     THEN '['+ C.name +']' 
     ELSE C.name 
     END
FROM     sys.columns C
JOIN     sys.tables T
ON       C.object_id  = T.object_id
JOIN     sys.schemas S
ON       S.schema_id  = T.schema_id
WHERE    T.name    = @TABLE_NAME
AND      S.name    = @SCHEMA_NAME
ORDER BY column_id


SET @vvc_ColumnList=''

OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @vvc_ColumnName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
  BEGIN
   SET @vvc_ColumnList = @vvc_ColumnList + @vvc_ColumnName

    -- get the details of the next column
   FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @vvc_ColumnName

  -- add a comma if we are not at the end of the row
   IF @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    SET @vvc_ColumnList = @vvc_ColumnList + ','
   END

 CLOSE TableCursor
 DEALLOCATE TableCursor

-- Now search for `foo`


SELECT *
FROM testing 
WHERE 'foo' in (@vvc_ColumnList );
```

**2nd Method**
In sql server you can get object id of table then using that object id you can fetch columns. In that case it will be as below:

**Step 1:** First get Object Id of table

```
select * from sys.tables order by name
```

**Step 2:** Now get columns of your table and search in it:

```
 select * from testing where 'foo' in (select name from sys.columns  where  object_id =1977058079)
```

Note: object_id is what you get fetch in first step for you relevant table

Comment: I tested it and it works, just give it a run @nsilva

Comment: Hi, I've just tried, I did a SELECT * FROM testing to find a value I want to return to check, but running the script just returned nothing. I've changed table name, and SELECT at the bottom to match the database i'm checking, there's nothing else I need to change right?

Comment: you just need to keep in mind that schemna name in this case dbo and table name are given correctly. I am giving table and schemna at start of procedure. Alternatively you can try 2nd method

Comment: If you go for first method, you need to create stored procedure!! @nsilva
But second method it too easy, just check that also

Comment: Object names are Unicode, use NVARCHAR. Do not write in-house quoting a-la `'['+ C.name +']' `, use [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx), you are not handling properly escape sequences in quoted identifiers. Always quote a name, not only if it contains space, there are many more problem chars (`\n`, `\t` obvious ones, but there a whole lot more in Unicode space).

Comment: Apart from issues mentioned by @RemusRusanu, the "first method" does not work in principle. It (badly) generates a string that contains comma-separated column names and uses that string in the `IN` clause which makes no sense and is equivalent to `WHERE 'foo' = 'column1,column2,column3'`, which is not going to find anything. It does make sense to build comma-separated list of columns, but it then must be used to [build dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2944612/11683).

Answer (score 1):

You can use in and you can get the column names dynamically and pass them to `IN` clause by making sql string and executing it using `execute sp_executesql`.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(2100)
declare @cols nvarchar(2000)
declare @toSearch nvarchar(200)
declare @tableName nvarchar(200)
set @tableName = 'tbltemp'
set @toSearch = '5' 
set @cols =(
 SELECT LEFT(column_name, LEN(column_name) - 1)
FROM (
    SELECT column_name + ', '
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = @tableName
    FOR XML PATH ('')
  ) c (column_name )
)
set @sql = 'select * from tbltemp where '''+ @toSearch + '''  in (' + @cols + ')';  
execute sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have int columns in your table.

Answer (score 1):

I took the idea from [ubaid ashraf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28718481/3357935), but made it actually work. Just change MyTableName here:

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + c.name 
    FROM sys.columns  c
    JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
    WHERE t.name != 'int'  AND t.name != 'bit' AND t.name !='date' AND t.name !='datetime'
        AND object_id =(SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE name='MyTableName')
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')
```

You could tweak it to your needs and add or remove conditions from the where column (the 't.name != 'int'  AND t.name != 'bit' etc. part), e.g. add 't.name != 'uniqueidentifier'' to avoid getting `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'myvalue' to data type int` type of errors..

Then **copy paste** the result into this query (otherwise it didn't work):

```
SELECT * from MyTableName where 'foo' in (COPY PASTE PREVIOUS QUERY RESULT INTO HERE)
```

Comment: did not work for me. it was like -->  ... where 1 in (calculation1, calculation2)

Comment: @ErayBalkanli - I just verified again and it does work. I don't understand from your comment what it did not work. If you could make it more clear I can try to help..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of the best ways of doing it

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns  a
inner join 
(
SELECT object_id
FROM sys.tables 
where 
type='U'--user table
and name like 'testing' 
) b on a.object_id=b.object_id
WHERE a.name like '%foo%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--Obtain object_id
SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE name = <your_table>


--look for desired value in specified columns using below syntax
SELECT * FROM <your_table> WHERE <VALUE_YOU_SEARCH_FOR> in
(SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = <your_table_object_id>
and name like '<if_you_have_multiple_columns_with_same_name_pattern>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with [BornToCode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34658608/1303952) and this script generates the queries to find a value in all columns of type varchar for any view (can be table) of the database:

```
DECLARE @id INT
declare @name nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @getid CURSOR
declare @value nvarchar(30)
set @value = 'x'

SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
SELECT object_id,name
FROM   sys.views

OPEN @getid
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getid INTO @id, @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

---------

SELECT  'SELECT * from ' + @name + ' where ''' + @value + ''' in (' + 
    STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + c.name 
    FROM sys.columns  c
    JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
    WHERE t.name = 'varchar'--  AND t.name != 'bit' AND t.name !='date' AND t.name !='datetime'
        AND object_id =(SELECT object_id FROM sys.views WHERE name=@name)
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')
    + ')' as 'query'

------
FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getid INTO @id, @name

END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table have indexes it can be better to seek column by column

```
DECLARE @TBL_NAME VARCHAR(100) = 'foo'
DECLARE @SEARCH_VALUE VARCHAR(100) = 'bar'
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT
    @QUERY += '
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ' + @tbl_name + '
        WHERE ' + NAME + ' = ''' + @SEARCH_VALUE + '''
        )
            PRINT ''The value exists in the column ' + name + '''
'
FROM SYS.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TYPE_NAME(SYSTEM_TYPE_ID) IN ('CHAR', 'VARCHAR', 'CHAR', 'VARCHAR')
    AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@TBL_NAME)
--PRINT @QUERY
EXEC(@QUERY)
```