# show the tables and columns of a value in Database

Tags: mysql

I have a big database and I do not know the tables name and columns of a value `11601` which is stored in the Database. Is it possible to show the tables and columns with this values `11601`?

Comment: Yes, but not without a fair amount of work.  you'd have to parse the system tables for all the tables, columns and loop though each table and column searching for that record, when a match is found, add that column, table to your output.  I don't think a full text search could return the table, column it was found in.  You may be able to increase the rate of search if you know the field's data type...

Comment: Read this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717868/sql-server-select-where-any-column-contains-x

Comment: @Christian good example; but not mySQL specific, MySQL has different system tables..  You could also do this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562457/search-for-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-mysql-database or http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34856/how-to-search-whole-mysql-database-for-a-particular-string for mysql specific