# How to search a column value of a particular table in SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Input :

`EMP` table has 100 columns. If we type any value for `@searchparameter`, it's like Google search. It has to check all the columns internally and display the relevant rows of all columns

```
EmpID    Ename    Designation   
-----------------------------    
1        swami      GM
2        kiran      test
```

Output :

@Search = 'GM'

```
EmpID    Ename    Designation   
-----------------------------    
1        swami      GM
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server SELECT where any column contains 'x'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717868/sql-server-select-where-any-column-contains-x)

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx)
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx)

And build your procedure using

- [DYNAMIC QUERIES (sp_executesql)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

You can find some examples in SO:

- [How do I find a value anywhere in a SQL Server Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/how-do-i-find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: I am not able to change the code as per my requirement . could you please help on this.

Comment: Have you a query that do searches in your table or you need a query?