# SQL Query on multiple conditional columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Pardon for the title I cant seem to figure out what could I do. I have a `MainTable` that have some columns that is defined in another table `DefTable`

Simplified because this columns runs from `Col1` to `Col99`

> MainTable

```
RowId Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
----- ---- ---- ---- ----
  1    Y   N    N    N
  2    N   Y    N    N
  3    N   N    N    Y
```

> DefTable

```
Key Description
--- -----------
 1  Logistics
 2  Warehouse
 3  Packaging
 4  MainLobby
```

Condition is:
If a column is tagged `Y` I should display the `Description` according to its key in the `DefTable`

Also I'm looking into the possibility of two or more Columns are ticked `Y`. If that happens. I should `Concatenate` the results like `Logistics, MainLobby`

> Expected output

```
RowId Description
----- -----------
  1   Logistics
  2   Warehouse
  3   MainLobby
```

> Possibility of multiple ticked columns

```
RowId Description
----- -----------
  1   Warehouse, MainLobby
```

I have been tinkering this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28718481/4466640) but I'm still stuck. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for .

Your Data Looks like :

**MainTable**

```
 SELECT *  INTO #MainTable FROM (
  VALUES(1,'Y','N','N','N'),
  (2,'N','Y','N','N'),
  (3,'N','N','N','Y')
  ) AS A(RowId ,Col1 ,Col2 ,Col3 ,Col4)
```

**DefTable**

```
 SELECT * INTO #DefTable FROM (
 VALUES(1,'Logistics'),
 (2,'Warehouse'),
 (3,'Packaging'),
 (4,'MainLobby')
 )AS A([Key],[Description])
```

**Query:**

```
 SELECT M.RowId ,
 CASE WHEN (Col1='Y' OR Col2='Y' OR Col3='Y' OR Col4='Y' )THEN D.Description ELSE '' END AS [Description] 
 FROM #MainTable M
 INNER JOIN #DefTable D ON D.[Key]=M.RowId
```

**Dynamic Method:**

```
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX),@COLUMNSQUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @COLUMNSQUERY=(SELECT 'CASE '+(SELECT  'WHEN '+COLUMN_NAME +'=''Y'' THEN [DESCRIPTION] ' 
    FROM [tempdb].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME like '#MainTable%' 
    and COLUMN_NAME <>'RowId' for xml path('') ) + 'ELSE '''' END AS [DESCRIPTION]' )

SET @QUERY=' SELECT M.RowId ,'+@COLUMNSQUERY + 'FROM #MainTable M
INNER JOIN #DefTable D ON D.[Key]=M.RowId'

EXEC (@QUERY)
```

**Note :** I've picked the columns of temp table from Temp db . Please replace it with your actual database  where your main table exists

Replace  this condition **`FROM [tempdb].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME like '#MainTable%'`**  with this  **`FROM [YourDatabaseName].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME like 'Your Main table Name%'`**

Comment: Yes this is acceptable when Im only limited to 4 items. but i got around 99 columns and possibly go more than 99.

Comment: I'e added the `Dynamic Method` as well . Now ,check the updated answer

Comment: Now you no need to hard code all of your 99+ columns in the code .you can simply use that dynamic code .

Answer (score 2):

You would use `Apply` operator (i.e. `CROSS APPLY`)

```
SELECT a.RowId, d.Description 
FROM MainTable  t
CROSS APPLY (
       VALUES (t.RowId, 1, t.Col1), (t.RowId, 2, t.Col2),
              (t.RowId, 3, t.Col3), (t.RowId, 4, t.Col4)
              ....
)a(RowId, Id, Cols)
INNER JOIN DefTable d ON d.[Key] = a.Id
WHERE a.Cols = 'Y'
```

Comment: Yes this is acceptable when Im only limited to 4 items. but i got around 99 columns and possibly go more than 99. Wanting to to be more dynamic and what if I have more than 2 fields tagged `Y`

Comment: Joining MainTable and DefTable on RowId doesn't seem fine. Please check.

Comment: @Hexxed... If you don't have periodically change the columns then this approach would useful else you would look into more dynamic way.

Comment: @YogeshSharma thank you this solution is helpful too