# How to get Sqlite3 column names containing a value?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a **sqlite3** table where it contains 0 and 1.
I would like to get the column names where the value is 1.
I have tried both description and pragma method and for some reason the result is incorrect.

Following are my attempts:

**.decription**

```
allResults = c.execute("SELECT * FROM db_1.hope5 WHERE Vehicle = '{}'".format(veh))
all_columnNames = [tup[0] for tup in allResults.description]
inputs_columnNames = all_columnNames[9:]
inputcheck = [tup[9:] for tup in allResults.fetchall()]
inputSelected = [val for i, val in enumerate(inputs_columnNames) if inputcheck[0][i] == 1]
```

**pragma**

```
c = connection.cursor()
        c.execute("PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(hope5)")
        names = [tup[1] for tup in c.fetchall()]
        names = names[2:]
        result = c.execute("SELECT * FROM hope5 WHERE Vehicle = '{}' ".format(veh))
        result = result.fetchall()
        test = [names[index] for index, val in enumerate(result[0][2:]) if val==1]
```

**Shape of the table**

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 0  |  0  |  1  |  0  | 0   |  1  |
|----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 1  |  0  |  0  |  0  | 1   |  0  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Based on my above code, the results need to be:

```
test = [A,C,E,F]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server SELECT where any column contains 'x'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717868/sql-server-select-where-any-column-contains-x)

Comment: @MichaelBianconi that link is SQL server and not python & Sqlite3!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was:

```
inputSelected = [val for i, val in enumerate(inputs_columnNames) if inputcheck[0][i] == 1]
```

where the inputcheck[0] should have been j. by changing to the following it worked:

```
inputSelected_append = []
for j in range(len(inputcheck)):
    inputSelected = [val for i, val in enumerate(inputs_columnNames) if inputcheck[j][i] == 1]
    inputSelected_append.append(inputSelected)
```