# Filter records with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are 4 attributes in a table. Only one attribute can be set to Y at a time. Is there a SQL Server function to find this.

[image: Valid values]

Comment: Do you want to identify records which have more than 1 set? Or do you only want to output valid records which only have 1 set?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717868/sql-server-select-where-any-column-contains-x. There are a couple of solutions for a similar problem.

Comment: I want to get the list of records which have more than one attribute set to Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following boolean expression to restrict at most one "Y" value among the attributes:

```sql
IIF(Attribute1 = 'Y', 1, 0) +
IIF(Attribute2 = 'Y', 1, 0) +
IIF(Attribute3 = 'Y', 1, 0) +
IIF(Attribute4 = 'Y', 1, 0) <= 1
```

Comment: @sivabalanarayanan . . . `<= 1` does not meet the requirements of your question.  It is surprising you accepted this.

Comment: It is surprising that both of us happen to be looking at this hours old question at the same moment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It works when I changed the condition to it > 1. One could have overlooked it. I accepted as I was thinking about CASE statements and IFF is a shorthand way for CASE.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a concatenation trick here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Attribute1 + Attribute2 + Attribute3 + Attribute4
      NOT LIKE '%Y%Y%';
```

But this would also match a record having `N` for all 4 attributes.  If you also want to insist on one `Y`, but not more than one `Y`, then use this version:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    Attribute1 + Attribute2 + Attribute3 + Attribute4 LIKE '%Y%' AND
    Attribute1 + Attribute2 + Attribute3 + Attribute4
      NOT LIKE '%Y%Y%';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to identify records as either "Valid" or "Invalid", then you could do something like this:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Sample','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Sample; --SELECT * FROM #Sample
CREATE TABLE #Sample (
    Attribute1 char(1) NOT NULL,
    Attribute2 char(1) NOT NULL,
    Attribute3 char(1) NOT NULL,
    Attribute4 char(1) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Sample (Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3, Attribute4)
VALUES ('Y','N','N','N')
    ,  ('N','Y','N','N')
    ,  ('N','N','Y','N')
    ,  ('N','N','N','Y')
    ,  ('N','N','Y','Y')

SELECT *
    , IsValid = IIF(LEN(REPLACE(CONCAT(s.Attribute1, s.Attribute2, s.Attribute3, s.Attribute4),'Y','')) >= 3, 'Valid', 'Invalid')
FROM #Sample s
```

Returns:

```
| Attribute1 | Attribute2 | Attribute3 | Attribute4 | IsValid | 
|------------|------------|------------|------------|---------| 
| Y          | N          | N          | N          | Valid   | 
| N          | Y          | N          | N          | Valid   | 
| N          | N          | Y          | N          | Valid   | 
| N          | N          | N          | Y          | Valid   | 
| N          | N          | Y          | Y          | Invalid |
```

The logic is....Take the 4 columns and combine them into a single string, so `Y,N,N,N` becomes `YNNN`. Then replace all instances of the letter 'Y' and get the length of the result. Since you know the original length was 4, now you know how many Y's were removed.

This is a classic trick for counting the number of times a string occurs in another string.

In my example, I treat zero or one Y's as valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @Attr TABLE(A1 CHAR,
A2 CHAR,
A3 CHAR,
A4 CHAR)

insert Into @Attr  VALUES('Y','N','N','N')
insert Into @Attr  VALUES('N','Y','N','N')
insert Into @Attr  VALUES('N','N','Y','N')
insert Into @Attr  VALUES('N','N','N','Y')
insert Into @Attr  VALUES('Y','N','Y','N')

SELECT * FROm @Attr

SELECT * FROM @Attr
WHERE 
((A2<>'Y' AND A3<>'Y' AND A4<>'Y' ) OR 
(A1<>'Y' AND A3<>'Y' AND A4<>'Y') OR 
(A1<>'Y' AND A2<>'Y' AND A4<>'Y') OR
(A1<>'Y' AND A2<>'Y' AND A3<>'Y'))
```

Answer (score 1):

In a `select` query (which seems sufficient for your purposes), then I would recommend:

```
select t.*
from t cross apply
     (select count(*) as num_ys
      from (values (attribute1), (attribute2), (attribute3), (attribute4)
           ) v(attr)
      where attr = 1
     ) v
where num_ys = 1;
```

The performance of `apply` in this case is actually quite good.  More importantly this makes it much simpler to generalize the query -- adding new attributes, or saying at least one "Y" and not more than 2 "N"s or whatever.