# Search in PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have this table in which I would like to implement search filter.

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_NAME TEXT,
 PASSWD TEXT,
 FIRST_NAME TEXT,
 LAST_NAME TEXT,
 LAST_LOGIN DATE,
 DATE_REGISTERED DATE,
 ROLE INTEGER,
 CAN_LOGIN INTEGER
)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE ACCOUNT

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT KEY1 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;
```

String searchString = "32";

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT
WHERE " + searchString + " IN (ID, USER_NAME, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) ORDER BY %S %S offset ? limit ?;
```

I get error

```
serverError: class java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Also I don't want to specify every table column in which I want to search. Is there a way to implement search in all columns by default? And just specify one column in which I don't want to search?

Comment: (1) Print out the query after the variable substitution.  (2) Include the error in your message.

Comment: Can you show me how? I have very little experience with SQL?

Comment: Check [How can I search all columns in a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922744/how-can-i-search-all-columns-in-a-table). Anyway `IN` will get you only exact matches.

Answer (score 2):

You have a type conversion problem with the `IN` list.  These all have to be the same type, so they are converted to the type of what is being compared.  And, there is a failure to convert strings to ints.

If you include single quotes, then your query should work:

```
WHERE '" + searchString + "' IN (ID, USER_NAME, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
```

Comment: Thanks. I get this when I have empty search string `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "null" Position: 30` How I can skip search if the String filter is empty?

Comment: I would suggest writing two different queries.

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522826/implement-search-filter-for-all-columns