# Testing for null inside SQL query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to implement search filter for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_NAME TEXT,
 PASSWD TEXT,
 FIRST_NAME TEXT,
 LAST_NAME TEXT,
 LAST_LOGIN DATE,
 DATE_REGISTERED DATE,
 ROLE INTEGER,
 CAN_LOGIN INTEGER
)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE ACCOUNT

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT KEY1 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;


SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT 
WHERE '" + searchString + "' IN (ID, USER_NAME, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
ORDER BY %S %S offset ? limit ?;
```

But when I have empty search filter I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "null" Position: 30
```

How can I edit the SQL query in a way that WHERE clause will be skipped if searchString is empty?

Here is the Java method:

```
public List<AccountsObj> list(int firstRow, int rowCount, String sortField, boolean sortAscending) throws SQLException
    {
        String SqlStatement = null;

        if (ds == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        String sortDirection = sortAscending ? "ASC" : "DESC";

        SqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT "
            + " WHERE '" + searchString + "' IN (ID, USER_NAME, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)"
            + " ORDER BY %S %S offset ? limit ? ";

        String sql = String.format(SqlStatement, sortField, sortDirection);

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<AccountsObj> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, firstRow);
            ps.setInt(2, rowCount);

            resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            resultList = ProcessorArrayList(resultSet);

            conn.commit();
            committed = true;

        }
        finally
        {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }

        return resultList;
    }
```

Comment: Whatever you do just stop for a moment. Your query looks very odd. In your application layer you probably have: 1.string concatenation 2. parameter binding 3. string substution. What if user provide `searchString` that will comment rest of query and `DROP DATABASE`?

Comment: Anyway it is probably duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519762/search-in-postgresql-table

Comment: It's a similar but the problem is different.

Comment: So you don't see any problem with mixing: `sql query string concatenation/parameter binding and string substitution`?

Comment: What if I set the search string as parameter of  prepared statement?

Comment: Please post your application code.

Comment: Here you are: http://pastebin.com/eEeTWEqK

Comment: Please add the most important method to your question and add tag `java`. And yes prepared statement are generally more secure than custom build queries.

Comment: Done. Can you give some advice how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL to check for a `null` search string you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM account WHERE ? IS NULL OR ? IN (user_name, first_name, last_name)
```

Here the `? IS NULL` will short-circuit if the parameter is `NULL` and the second part will not be evaluated.

Note that, I've used two parameter bindings with the same value (your search string) here and that the `ID` column is gone - you cannot mix `varchar` and `integer` in the `IN` clause.

**Edit** For wildcard searches you can use `LIKE` or `ILIKE` (for case-insensitive searches)

```
SELECT * FROM account WHERE 
     (trim(?) = '') IS NOT FALSE 
    OR user_name like ? 
    OR first_name like ? 
    OR last_name like ?
```

Using a prepared statement you would call it like this (note that you have to bind the same parameter four times)

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

    ps.setString(1, searchString);
    ps.setString(2, searchString);
    ps.setString(3, searchString);
    ps.setString(4, searchString );

    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        // read data 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, How I Can add wildcard character? For example I would like to search part of a string `%valu%'

Comment: @Peter Penzov The straight forward way to go would be to use `like` or `ilike` (case-insensitive), e.g. `WHERE  ? IS NULL  OR user_name like ?   OR first_name like ?  OR last_name like ?`

Comment: Also, you could go for fulltext search, see here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-SEARCH

Comment: Can you give me please example how I can use the example from the link with Java code and prepared statement? It's not very clear for me how I can use `to_tsvector('english', body) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'friend');` in my case.

Comment: Something like this `user_name::tsvector @@ to_tsquery(?)` where the search string would be like `valu:*`. But the wildcard works only for prefix searches (`:*value:*` will not work) - so this may not be the best solution for you, but it's always good to know all your options

Comment: Can you please update your post? I'm totally confused.

Comment: By the way with `WHERE ? IS NULL OR ?` I get only the rows with empty data. Filter is not skipped.

Comment: I have some progress, please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522826/implement-search-filter-for-all-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this line of your java code :

```
+ (searchString == null || searchString.length == 0 ) ? "" : (" WHERE '" + searchString + "' IN (ID, USER_NAME, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)")
```

It basically checks if searchString is empty, and adds the line only if it is not

Comment: I get incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: you only need to change that one line

Comment: I get bad operand type String for unary operator '+++'

Comment: I get incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean