# Implement search filter for all columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I found this search example in PostgreSQL http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-SEARCH

I tried to implement this code for this table this way:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_NAME TEXT,
 PASSWD TEXT,
 FIRST_NAME TEXT,
 LAST_NAME TEXT,
 LAST_LOGIN DATE,
 DATE_REGISTERED DATE,
 ROLE INTEGER,
 CAN_LOGIN INTEGER
)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE ACCOUNT

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT KEY1 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;
```

**Java code**

```
public List<AccountsObj> list(int firstRow, int rowCount, String sortField, boolean sortAscending) throws SQLException
    {
        String SqlStatement = null;

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        String sortDirection = sortAscending ? "ASC" : "DESC";

        SqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT "
//            + " WHERE ? IS NULL OR ? IN (USER_NAME, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)"
            + " WHERE to_tsvector('english', USER_NAME || ' ' ) @@ plainto_tsquery(?)"
            + " ORDER BY %S %S offset ? limit ? ";

        String sql = String.format(SqlStatement, sortField, sortDirection);

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<AccountsObj> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setString(1, searchString);
            ps.setInt(2, firstRow);
            ps.setInt(3, rowCount);

            resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            resultList = ProcessorArrayList(resultSet);

            conn.commit();
            committed = true;

        }
        finally
        {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }

        return resultList;
    }
```

But I have two issues. When search string is empty the table is also empty. How I can solve this? Also how I can implement this search for every table column?

P.S I tried `WHERE to_tsvector('english', USER_NAME || ' ' ) @@ plainto_tsquery(?) IS NOT NULL`

But search filter is not applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add your 'null guard' to the the fulltext search and use `to_tsquery` instead of `plainto_tsquery` (in order for prefix search to work).

```
SqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT "
    + " WHERE (trim(?) = '') IS NOT FALSE"
    + " OR to_tsvector('english', USER_NAME || ' ' || FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME ) @@  to_tsquery(?)"
    + " ORDER BY user_name ASC offset ? limit ? ";
```

and add the `searchString` to your `PreparedStatement` a second time

```
 ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

 ps.setString(1, searchString);
 ps.setString(2, searchString);
 ps.setInt(3, firstRow);
 ps.setInt(4, rowCount);
```

**Note** using a fulltext search you will not be able to search for word-parts (like `%user%`, `%name` or `us%name`). You can search for prefixes though, e.g. `user:*`

Comment: Very strange. When I load the page I see rows of data generated, but when I switch table pages now rows are displayed.

Comment: When I type something into search filter again I can see some filtered data. But when filter is empty again there are no rows displayed.

Comment: @Peter Penzov could this be a problem with the offset you're passing in? When the offset is bigger than the number of rows, no data will be returned (e.g. the filtered query returns 10 rows, but the offset is 11)

Comment: Also note that the guard will only work for `null` and not for empty search strings

Comment: I tested this: I removed this line `ORDER BY %S %S offset ? limit ?` and the table is displayed without pagination. But the bug is still present with empty filter. Looks like we have `' '` not null.

Comment: How can we make guard work for null and for empty search strings

Comment: @Peter Penzov updated my answer (the SQL string) to work with `null`, empty strings and blank strings (" ")

Comment: It's working fine. Can I ask you one last thing. How I can search only part of the string like this - %value%

Comment: please see the last partof my answer. use `:*` as wildcard

Comment: Is there other solution?

Comment: yep. see the edit in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: Yes but this includes totally changing the SQL query. Can we change a little bit this SQL query in order to have this functionality?