# MySQL update field where value is x

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I've got a table named 'ids' as follow:

```
ID | id1 | id2 | id3 
---|-----|-----|----- 
25-|--2--|--3--|--4--
---|-----|-----|-----
15-|--7--|--22-|--1-- 
---|-----|-----|-----
```

etc

Now I want to change those fields into null, that contain the value 3 
and where ID=25. 
Usually You use the term:

`UPDATE ids SET columnName = value WHERE ID=25.`

But in this case I cannot determine the columname and I must find it out with the help of the value in the field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I search all columns in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922744/how-can-i-search-all-columns-in-a-table)

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of (appallingly) poor design

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE ids
SET 
   id1 = IF(id1=3, NULL, id1),
   id2 = IF(id2=3, NULL, id2),
   id3 = IF(id3=3, NULL, id3)
WHERE 3 IN (id1, id2, id3) AND ID = 25
```