# How to find corrupt record with unicode character in SQL and delete the record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with huge sets of rows. There are a few record with a strange unicode character like: \uDB6D

Due this I get an error in my SQL report builder:

> ERROR: An exception has occurred in data set 'DataSet1'. Details: System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate Unicode character \uDB6D at index 184 to specified code page.

I tried several queries but I am unable to find the row with the unicode.
How to trace the record and eventually delete it?

These are the queries I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable
WHERE SomeString LIKE N'%�%';

SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable
WHERE SomeString LIKE CONCAT('%',UNICODE(0xDB6D),'%');
```

Comment: *"I tried several queries but I am unable to find the row with the unicode. "* And what were those queries? There's no need to us to tell, as an answer, what you already did and for you to tell us "That doesn't work."

Comment: Both of those solutions work for me: [db<fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c41b1a7b0399d56277c36326b5cb7463). YOu don't, perhaps, literally have `'\uDB6D'` in the string, do you?

Comment: `UNICODE(0xDB6D)` makes no sense. You want `NCHAR(56173)`. `DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(50) = 0xDB6D` doesn't do what you want either, because SQL Server uses little-endian encoding. Finally, 巛 is `U+5DDB CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5DDB`, which is neither `0xdb6d` nor `0x6ddb`, so I'm not sure where that comes from.

Comment: @Larnu it seems like there is a �    somewhere in a string. I use where ... like N'%�%' it give me all the rows back :/

Comment: Well, `�` and `巛` are *completely* different characters... No wonder this didn't work. It's like having `WHERE [Column] LIKE '%a%'` and expecting columns which have a `z` in them to be returned...

Comment: The reason `like N'%�%'` won't work is that collation rules will (mostly) ignore invalid characters. Use a binary collation override (`COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2`), and be sure to use `NCHAR` with the exact code point rather than copy-pasting the replacement character.

Comment: Thanks. @SQLPolice gave the right answer. Simple, consice and understandable. Your comments Larnu and Jeroen where a bit over complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`charindex` does the magic:

```
select *
from dbo.TestTable
where charindex(nchar(0xDB6D), SomeString) > 0
```

Comment: is it also possible to search for the nchar in every column? so : where charindex(nchar(0xDB6D), *) > 0

Comment: @YdB It is possible, but there is no simple statement for this. If you want to search in all columns, you need to write a procedure which generates the code for you. The principle is shown here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52715388/2504785 (but you will need to adapt the code for your question)

Comment: Thanks ! If there is another unicode char not found like: \uDB4E
Will this then be: where charindex(nchar(0xDB4E), SomeString) > 0
@SQLPolice?

Comment: @YdB yes, exactly. Pleased that it works!

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you try to find just "DB6D" string? I just think simple.

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderLines
WHERE OrderLines.ItemDescription LIKE '%DB6D%'
```

Comment: Tried this, no results :(

Comment: In this question, DB6D is the code for one single character, it is not a string.

Answer (score -2):

Or you can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderLines
WHERE OrderLines.ItemDescription LIKE '%' + nchar(56173) + '%'
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.