# SQL - Find specific value in a specific table

Tags: sql

Say I have a table called "Team" with the following columns:

**ID**, **MemberName** ,**ManagerName**,**Title**

And I would like to retrieve all rows where a value "John" exists.

Assume "John" exists in a row for the MemberName column, and that "John" would exist in another row under the "ManagerName" column.

*Please assume would have large number of columns. Greater than 50, and do would not know where the value would fall under statically.*

Comment: You have to specify each column to be searched. Dynamic SQL can perhaps be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an exact match for "John" you can use following query:

```
Select * 
From Team 
Where MemberName = 'John' or ManagerName = 'John'
```

If you need all rows where "John" could be a part of the string then you can use `like`:

```
Select * 
From Team 
Where MemberName like '%John%' or ManagerName like '%John%'
```

Comment: Sorry, I specified the post. Please assume I want to search a large table, and do not know which column exactly the value would be under

Comment: Note that standard compliant SQL uses single quotes for string literals. (Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. a column named John.)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need to specify all the columns your are searching from in SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM Team WHERE 'John' IN (col1, col2, col3, ..., colN) ;
```

However that depends.

If you are using MySQL you can Search Table Data. From the MySQL Workbench right click the table , and choose Search Table Data.

If you are using PostgreSQL take a look at the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52715388/10436747